# Firebase Email Authentication sign-in closure issue swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here below is my sign in button function that checks if any of the textfields are empty and alerts user to fill in all fields if so. If all fields are filled in correctly then a sign-in link should be sent to email but i keep gettin this error specifically referring to the the authentication closure but I'm not sure what to do [image]

```
   func handleSignUpError(error: Error){
       let localizedDescription = AuthErrorCode.init(rawValue: error._code)!
       switch localizedDescription {
       case .invalidEmail:
           print("Wrong email ")
       case .invalidPhoneNumber:
           print("Wrong phone # ")
       case .operationNotAllowed:
           print("Operation not allowed")
       case .userNotFound:
           print("User not found")
       case .tooManyRequests:
           print("Too many requests ")
       default: fatalError("Fatal error")}}
   
   // Validates whether fields are filled out and creates user in database upon login
@IBAction func SignUpButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {if FirstNameField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" || LastNameField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" || PhoneNumberField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" || EmailField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" {
           let missingNameAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Unable to complete Sign-Up", message: "Please fill in all the fields", preferredStyle: .alert)
           let missingNameAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
           missingNameAlert.addAction(missingNameAlertAction)
           self.present(missingNameAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
       } else {
           view.endEditing(true)
               let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings()
               actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID("com.IMHOTECHP.GiftMe")
               actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
               actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: "wealthvert.com")
           
               Auth.auth().sendSignInLink(toEmail: EmailField.text!, actionCodeSettings: actionCodeSettings){ error in
                   if let error = error { self.handleSignUpError(error: error.localizedDescription as! Error)
             return }}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to force cast `error.localizedDescription`, which is a `String` to an `Error` on this line:

```
error.localizedDescription as! Error
```

Instead, you should probably just pass `error`, like this:

```
self.handleSignUpError(error: error)
```

Or, if you want to change it to a `String`, alter your `handleSignUpError` to accept a `String` instead of an error and pass `error.localizedDescription` to it.

In general, in Swift you will want to be very careful of using `!` to force cast or force unwrap anything. Instead, familiarize yourself with `if let` and `as ?` to bind optionals or cast types safely.

Comment: @colbythegoat Did this help you or answer your question?